# Is there any way I can embed a small piece of recording on ELU?

Tags: discussion

I want to know whether there are any ways I can embed recording on this site? I have a little piece of recording and I've listened many times but still can't clearly understand what the man is saying. I want some native speakers to help me on it.

Comment: I think asking people to transcribe a recording for you would be too localized/off-topic, anyway.

Comment: ... you can always try our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage), though.

Comment: I doubt ELU/SO provides for storing users' audio files, so you'd have to put your file somewhere else on the internet and provide a link to it here. One easy (and free!) facility is [dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com/). You can use it to store "backup" copies of stuff you don't want to lose when your hard drive dies, plus dropbox gives you a shareable link to any files/folders you want to make accessible to others. There are others (RapidShare, for example), but I like DropBox.

Comment: According to [this Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97610/181225) posted last year, you can upload your sound file to soundcloud.com, insert the link to the file into your Question or Answer, and then viewers will see a clickable embedded player that plays your file.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel That would be an answer.

Answer (score -1):

If there are no copyright problems with it, e-mail it to me and I'll host it for you.