# I have a recording 1) How do I upload it onto ELU?

Tags: support, feature-request

The recording is circa five minutes long, it's between me and my companion. I suppose I could transcribe the entire script but

1) it would become tedious to read
2) it would take too long for me, and lose its *humour*
3) it's nice for non-native speakers to listen to (I think!)
4) ELUers will at long last hear my accent

I would in any case write my question, which is *kinda* contained in the recording. 
Can I upload it from my computer? Although first I'd need to figure how to download it from my mobile phone; a recently bought, second-hand, iPhone 4s. If not, is there a quick and *easy* way?

P.S This is an almost duplicate of [Is there any way I can embed a small piece of recording on ELU?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2580/is-there-any-way-i-can-embed-a-small-piece-of-recording-on-elu) But the suggested answer is unhelpful.

Comment: You'll have to upload it to a third-party file hosting site, and then link to it from your answer. Unfortunately, I don't have any good advice on [how to catch an elephant](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061113182047AAMKpIp).

Comment: If you're willing to spend $2.00 and have a (or are willing to set up a free) Dropbox account, it looks like the [DropVox app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dropvox-record-voice-memos/id416288287?mt=8) will let you upload voice memos from your iPhone easily.

Comment: @DanBron ahh "apps" for me an unknown identity. I really am a noobie (read virgin) where smart phones are concerned. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: One of our ELL users sometimes posts audio clips on [*audioscraps*](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/), which seems to work very well from my point of view when accessing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the SE engine does not provide any means of uploading anything but an image file. I doubt there is enough of a use for this for the suggestion to ever be implemented. However, there are many, many free sites that let you upload arbitrary content and make it easy to play it back.

Another option would be to use a service like Dropbox. Once you have uplodaed it (in the case of Dropbox, just add it to your Public folder), copy the public link and paste it into your question/answer. For example, here are the first few seconds of a recording of summertime I made with some friends:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14062712/summertime.mp3

If you click on the link, you can play it back without downloading anything.

Comment: Hmmm a black screen, I was hoping one could listen to the recording and still remain on ELU. Five minutes listening to two people yapping is perhaps too long. And having to open an account, upload, download bla bla sounds complicated.  P.S. Good rendition!

Comment: @Mari-LouA no, it won't be possible unless the SE developpers decide to implement it and I very much doubt they will. It is not that useful apart from fringe cases like the on you have brought up here. PS. Thanks :)